# Regex: Handle parameters

Tags: .net, regex

I want to parse some text that has the form

```
(<paramID><paramValue>)*(LastValue)*
```

Where paramID is the ID of the parameter and paramValue is almost anything that doesn't doesn't contain potential paramID's(so we can parse it unambiguously).

The main things to note are:

1. The first paramID may be optional.
2. paramValues can use grouping. Anything inside the grouping is treated as one token, even what seems to be paramID's.
3. Each paramValue is parsed greedily except the last, which is parsed lazily. (I realize this makes different orderings of the same parameters have a different interpretation, but the interpretation itself is always well defined and easily understood)

paramID = `"\s-[^\s\[\(\{\\""]+"`
paramValue = basically what is in between paramID's. Since this might contain things like look like paramID's but because they are inside a "group", they need to be ignored.

e.g.,

```
First Param Value -p1 Second Param Value -p2[Third-Param-Value] -X "-Fourth -Param -Value" -pl LastParamValue Last Value
```

should be parsed in the obvious way.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @ShaiCohen Shouldn't it be obvious? I need a regex to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to tokenize the expression as follows:

- Groups in brackets.

  - Using [balanced groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html) you may end up with something like `(?>(?'o'\[)[^][]*)+(?>[^][]*(?'-o'\]))+` for `[...]`. This allows groups nesting.
  - Similar expressions may be produced for `{...}` and `(...)` groups
- Groups in quotes (with possible escaped quotes within)
- Parameters names starting with a dash preceded by spaces
- And value parts as series of non-space characters surrounded by spaces. These later would be concatenated for all parameters but the last one. For the last parameter only the first value would be taken, whilst others would constitute the last value.

So the tokenizer expression is:

```
(?x)
  \s*(?<token> (?>(?'o'\[)[^][]*)+(?>[^][]*(?'-o'\]))+ )\s*  # balanced [...] group
| \s*(?<token> (?>(?'o'\{)[^{}]*)+(?>[^{}]*(?'-o'\}))+ )\s*  # balanced {...} group
| \s*(?<token> (?>(?'o'\()[^()]*)+(?>[^()]*(?'-o'\)))+ )\s*  # balanced (...) group
| \s*(?<token> "(?:\\"|[^"])*" )\s*   # quoted group with possible escaped quotes within
| \s*(?<token> -[^\s"({[]+ )          # parameter name
| (?<token> \s*\S+\s* )               # parameter value part not in group/quotes
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fx%29%0d%0a++%5cs*%28%3f%3ctoken%3e+%28%3f%3e%28%3f%27o%27%5c%5b%29%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%29%2b%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%28%3f%27-o%27%5c%5d%29%29%2b+%29%5cs*++%23+balanced+%5b...%5d+group%0d%0a%7c+%5cs*%28%3f%3ctoken%3e+%28%3f%3e%28%3f%27o%27%5c%7b%29%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%29%2b%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%28%3f%27-o%27%5c%7d%29%29%2b+%29%5cs*++%23+balanced+%7b...%7d+group%0d%0a%7c+%5cs*%28%3f%3ctoken%3e+%28%3f%3e%28%3f%27o%27%5c%28%29%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%29%2b%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%28%3f%27-o%27%5c%29%29%29%2b+%29%5cs*++%23+balanced+%28...%29+group%0d%0a%7c+%5cs*%28%3f%3ctoken%3e+%22%28%3f%3a%5c%5c%22%7c%5b%5e%22%5d%29*%22+%29%5cs*+++%23+quoted+group+with+possible+escaped+quotes+within%0d%0a%7c+%5cs*%28%3f%3ctoken%3e+-%5b%5e%5cs%22%28%7b%5b%5d%2b+%29++++++++++%23+parameter+name%0d%0a%7c+%28%3f%3ctoken%3e+%5cs*%5cS%2b%5cs*+%29+++++++++++++++%23+parameter+value+part+not+in+group%2fquotes&i=First+Param+Value+-p1+Second+Param+Value+-p2%5bThird-Param-Value%5d+-p3%5bnested+%5bparam+%22value%22%5d+%5d+-p4%7bnested+%7b+-param+%22+%7d+%7d+-p5%28nested+%28+%28%29+-param+%5d+%5d%22%5b%29+%29+-X+%22-Fourth+-Param%5c%22+-Value%22+-pl+%22Last+Param+Value%22+Last+Value)

Then we need to scan through tokens and collect parameter-value pairs appropriately:

```
var paramDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var currParam = "<FIRST>";
var currValues = new List<string>();
var lastParam = currParam;
foreach (var token in tokensRegex.Matches(expression)
    .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["token"].Value))
{
    if (token.StartsWith("-"))
    {
        // This is a paramater name. Store collected value
        // for the previous one and reset currXXX
        if (currParam == "<FIRST>" && currValues.Count == 0)
        {
            // The first param has its own name so don't add the default one.
            // Set the param name only
            currParam = token;
        }
        else
        {
            paramDict.Add(currParam, string.Join("", currValues));
            currParam = token;
            currValues = new List<string>();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        currValues.Add(token);
    }
}

// If the last value list has more that one item, set the first item
// as the last param value and the rest as the last value.
if (currValues.Count > 1)
{
    paramDict[currParam] = currValues[0];
    paramDict["<LAST>"] = string.Join("", currValues.Skip(1));
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bg1jxp